# Calculate $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos^3k}{n+k}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\cos^3k}{n+k}$$

$3\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{{{\cos }^3}k}}{{n + k}}}  = \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{{\cos 3k - 3\cos k}}{{n + k}}}  = \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\cos 3\left( {k - n} \right) - 3\cos \left( {k - n} \right)}}{k}}  = $$

$$\displaystyle= \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\cos 3k\cos 3n + \sin 3k\sin 3n}}{k} } - \frac{3}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\cos k\cos n + \sin k\sin n}}{k}} =$$

$$\displaystyle= \frac{{\cos 3n}}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\cos 3k}}{k}}  + \frac{{\sin 3n}}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\sin 3k}}{k}}  - \frac{{3\cos n}}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\cos k}}{k}}  - \frac{{3\sin n}}{4}\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\frac{{\sin k}}{k}} $$

Comment: The series $\sum {\sin (ak)\over k}$ and $\sum {\cos (ak)\over k}$ are convergent for every $a\neq 0,$ due to the Dirichlet test. Hence the limit is equal $0.$